Ignore trailing commas in CSV file when using CsvHelper?
I need to read a CSV file with a trailing comma at the end of each line:
column1,column2, // header
value1,value2,   // values

Note that the CSV file has only two columns. However the trailing comma at the end makes CsvHelper think there are 3 columns. Is there any option to tell CsvHelper to ignore the trailing comma?
    // embedded file content in code to make this example complete
    // and easy to execute/test for others
    string input =
        """
        headerColumn1,headerColumn2,
        dataValue1,dataValue2,
        """;
        
    var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var ms = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(input));
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(ms);
    
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = true,
    };
    
    using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config);
    
    csvReader.Read();
    var numberOfColumns = csvReader.Parser.Record.Length;
    Console.WriteLine
        (
            // output: number of detected columns: 3
            // note that the input only contains two columns
            // and a trailing comma
            $"number of detected columns: {numberOfColumns}"
        );


I know you will be annoyed at me, but your csv input actually does have three columns. That's just how csv works. What's wrong with reading in the third column and just not using it since it will always be empty?

@topsail no, I well understand that this might be valid CSV. However it's a little bit annonying when e.g. you compare against expected column names, where I would not include an empty column. Anyway, I can also filter that out manually. Jost hoped there would be an easier way.

Do you read to a model? Or do you need a more dynamic approach? Do all of your input files have trailing commas always or just some specific ones of them always or arbitrary ones sometimes?

all inputs have it and I am manually reading. I ended up reading the raw Record (string[]) and removing the last field after checking that it's really empty.

You can always remove the last comma of each line as the first step, using something as a TrimEnd(','), for example.

I don't really see how you would do that using CSVHelper library.

Careful, if the last "real" field is empty (value,,) , this will remove both end commas, making the line illegal

Fair point. the good old str =  str.EndsWith(",") ? str.Substring(0,  str.Length - 1) : str would be more sensitive.

This very much depends on what you are trying to do.
If you want a count of the non empty columns, you could do something like this.
using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config);    
csvReader.Read();
csvReader.ReadHeader();
var numberOfColumns = csvReader.HeaderRecord.Count(hr => hr != string.Empty);

If you are using a class to read the records, CsvHelper automatically ignores the trailing comma, i.e. the empty column.
string input =
"""
headerColumn1,headerColumn2,
dataValue1,dataValue2,
""";
 
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
};

var streamReader = new StringReader(input);   
using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config); 

var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Foo>();

foreach (var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"headerColumn1: {record.headerColumn1}");
    Console.WriteLine($"headerColumn2: {record.headerColumn2}");
}
        
public class Foo
{
    public string headerColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string headerColumn2 { get; set; }
}

If you are doing something more dynamic, I would need to know what you are trying to do.

thanks, I solved it by manually checking/removing the last column. I want to do strict CSV validation and e.g. GetRecords ignores silently if there are more columns in the CSV. That's why I do manual validation, comparing all columns against an array of columns I define in advance.
